# how to convert c struct with void* to c#

Tags: c#, c

I'm write a plugin with c# . the program with c# will use a dll which writes by c ,so I have to call c function in my c# program ,but unfortunately the c function's parameter is a struct and it is so complex that I never find any
 help information about how to convert it to c# parameter.

the struct has an embedded function and void* parameter ,I didn't find anyway to convert them to c#.

the struct is mostly like this

```
struct first_struct{
    char*           parameter1;
    int             parameter2;
    unsigned long   parameter3;
    unsigned short  parameter4;
    void*           parameter5;
    int             (*parameter6)(int,void *);
    second_struct   parameter7;
};

struct second_struct{
    char          parameter8[64] ;
    char         parameter9[256];
};
```

I want change this c struct to c# struct but I have no idea how to do it

---

thanks @Biesi Grr  and @Ian Abbott ‘s help it sames that I can change the c struct to c# like that.

```
public delegate int parameter6(int volcnt, System.IntPtr vod);
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
 public struct csharp_firstSturct
 {

     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] 
     public string parameter1;
     public int    parameter2;
     public ulong  parameter3;
     public ushort parameter4;  
     public System.IntPtr  parameter5;
     public parameter6 m_parameter6;
}
```

but I still has no idea about how to convert parameter7 from C to C#,what should I do to convert parameter7 form c to c#.

Comment: You can use an `IntPtr` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: `struct second_struct` has syntax errors. `char[64] parameter8;` should be `char parameter8[64];` (similarly for `parameter9`).

Comment: Presumably `parameter6` is a pointer to a "callback" handler function? If the callback function is to be implemented as a C# function, you will need to change `parameter6` to a **delegate**, something like `public delegate int parameter6(int, IntPtr);`

Comment: `unsigned long` in C is not the same as `ulong` in C#

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `char` arrays are null terminated strings you can do it the following way

```
public delegate int parameter6(int volcnt, System.IntPtr vod);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct csharp_firstSturct
{

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string parameter1;
    public int    parameter2;
    public ulong  parameter3;
    public ushort parameter4;
    public System.IntPtr  parameter5;
    public parameter6 m_parameter6;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public second_struct parameter7;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct second_struct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
    public string parameter8;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string parameter9;
}
```